# Математические действия с декоратором

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть декоратор и декорируемая функция. Декоратор должен умножать полученое значение из декорируемой функции на 2. Никак не могу понять как это можно реализовать, ведь выходит типовая ошибка `NoneType`. Вот пример:

```
def timesFunc(func):
    def wrapper(arg1,arg2):
        print("до")
        func(arg1,arg2)*2 #тут выдает ошибку. надо умножить значение на 2
        print("после")
    return wrapper

@timesFunc
def addNumbers(a,x):
    print(a+x)
addNumbers(2,3)
```

Comment: `func(arg1,arg2) * 2` - здесь вы умножаете результат выполнения функции на 2. Но функция возвращает `None`, ведь в ней нет `return`. И да, из декоратора тоже надо бы что-то возвращать. P.S. если выдает ошибку, почему бы ее не приложить к вопросу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нужно забывать о return`ах

```
def timesFunc(func):
    def wrapper(arg1, arg2):
        print("до")
        result = func(arg1, arg2)
        print(result)
        print("после")
        result *= 2
        print(result)
        return result
    return wrapper


@timesFunc
def addNumbers(a, x):
    return a + x

addNumbers(2, 3)
```